# Eclipse fails to update Maven index while behind company proxy

Tags: java, eclipse, proxy, m2eclipse, m2e

Eclipse Mars m2e plugin fails to download repository index updates on startup. I run Eclipse behind a company firewall but the proxy settings work fine for "check for updates", "eclipse marketplace", and eclipse's built-in browser.

I have tried the following:

1. Deleting the cache directory `\eclipse\p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository\cache` and then refreshing the repositories. Preferences -> Install Update -> Available Software Sites => select the entry and click "Reload"
2. Adding `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` to `-vmargs` in eclipse.ini

**Edit:** Proxy configurations are correctly set in $HOME/.m2/settings.xml
**Edit:** Seems like a bug. So I raised a bug request with eclipse.org. You can view it [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=478735)

Due to this issue, eclipse fails to search and add dependency from maven repositories.

Here is the error in .metadata/.log

```
eclipse.buildId=4.5.0.I20150603-2000
java.version=1.8.0_60
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_IN
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 4 0 2015-09-30 14:39:59.820
!MESSAGE Unable to update index for central|https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
!STACK 0
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:107)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:156)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:175)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:120)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:330)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:319)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:241)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:271)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:228)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:199)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:79)
        at io.takari.aether.okhttp.OkHttpAetherClient.execute(OkHttpAetherClient.java:154)
        at io.takari.aether.okhttp.OkHttpAetherClient.get(OkHttpAetherClient.java:100)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.index.nexus.AetherClientResourceFetcher.retrieve(AetherClientResourceFetcher.java:79)
        at org.apache.maven.index.updater.AbstractResourceFetcher.retrieve(AbstractResourceFetcher.java:35)
        at org.apache.maven.index.updater.DefaultIndexUpdater.downloadIndexProperties(DefaultIndexUpdater.java:452)
        at org.apache.maven.index.updater.DefaultIndexUpdater.access$100(DefaultIndexUpdater.java:75)
        at org.apache.maven.index.updater.DefaultIndexUpdater$IndexAdaptor.setProperties(DefaultIndexUpdater.java:607)
        at org.apache.maven.index.updater.DefaultIndexUpdater.fetchAndUpdateIndex(DefaultIndexUpdater.java:788)
        at org.apache.maven.index.updater.DefaultIndexUpdater.fetchAndUpdateIndex(DefaultIndexUpdater.java:135)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.index.nexus.NexusIndexManager.updateRemoteIndex(NexusIndexManager.java:1127)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.index.nexus.NexusIndexManager.updateIndex(NexusIndexManager.java:1084)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.index.nexus.NexusIndexManager$1.run(NexusIndexManager.java:656)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.index.nexus.IndexUpdaterJob.run(IndexUpdaterJob.java:72)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Comment: If you are using corporate internet, your employer may be analyzing your web traffic and using self-signed certificates. (See [Is it common practice for companies to MITM HTTPS traffic?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/107542/141087)) To confirm if this is the case, open Firefox to an HTTPS site, click the lock icon in the adddress bar, and click the arrow to view more details. If it says "Verified by <name of employer>", then it's an HTTPS issue.

Answer (score 2):

I've found solution. It's quite simple. After some code investigation I've found following thing:
https://github.com/eclipse/m2e-core/blob/releases/1.6/1.6.2.20150902-0002/org.eclipse.m2e.core/src/org/eclipse/m2e/core/internal/embedder/MavenImpl.java#L1226

So m2e scans proxy list and trying to find correct by protocol. If you look at central url: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2. It's starts from "https".

Your proxy settings should looks like that (one proxy for http and second for https):

```
<proxies>
  <proxy>
    <active>true</active>
    <protocol>http</protocol>
    <host>myproxy.company.com</host>
    <port>8080</port>
  </proxy>
    <proxy>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>https</protocol>
      <host>myproxy.company.com</host>
      <port>8080</port>
    </proxy>
</proxies>
```

Comment: Where do we find our proxy settings?

Answer (score 0):

Although you have configured proxy in eclispe, you have to do the same config for maven, into `settinggs.xml` file. Here you have my proxy configuration section:

```
<proxies>
  <proxy>
    <active>true</active>
    <protocol>http</protocol>
    <host>myproxy.company.com</host>
    <port>8080</port>
  </proxy>
</proxies>
```

Then you have to ensure in eclipse that you are using the configured `settings.xml` file, in `window`->`preferences`-`maven`->`user settings`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Proxy configurations are correctly set in $HOME/.m2/settings.xml

Comment: So, what happens if you run `mvn compile` from console? Does it work this way?

Comment: If maven works ok, and eclipse points to the same `settings.xml` ... can you launch `reindex` button from `window`->`preferences`-`maven`->`user settings`? what happens?

Comment: Failed.
`!MESSAGE Updating the index from remote failed. Version: 1.0.0.v20150617-0732
!STACK 0
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to dev.eclipse.org:443 [dev.eclipse.org/198.41.30.200] failed: Connection timed out: connect`

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand why it is trying to access `dev.eclipse.org`, it make no sense for me. Connection time out points to proxy error, but if everything is right configured, I can not figure out what's happen.

Answer (score 0):

Maven uses its own proxy settings, defined in *.m2/settings.xml*. You can find the settings used my m2e plugin in Eclipse's menu: Windows / Preferences / Maven / User Settings. Remember to hit the Update Settings -button after editing:

```
<!-- proxies
 | This is a list of proxies which can be used on this machine to connect to the network.
 | Unless otherwise specified (by system property or command-line switch), the first proxy
 | specification in this list marked as active will be used.
 |-->
<proxies>
  <!-- proxy
   | Specification for one proxy, to be used in connecting to the network.
   |
  <proxy>
    <id>optional</id>
    <active>true</active>
    <protocol>http</protocol>
    <username>proxyuser</username>
    <password>proxypass</password>
    <host>proxy.host.net</host>
    <port>80</port>
    <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
  </proxy>
  -->
</proxies>
```

Comment: Proxy configurations are correctly set in $HOME/.m2/settings.xml

Comment: Are you definitely using the $HOME/.m2/settings.xml also in m2e/eclipse?

Comment: Yes, that is affirmative.