# eclipse mars: rebuild index of maven central repository stuck

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

Eclipse Mars is failing to rebuilding index of https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2. Its stuck at 0%.

No Proxy.
Happening in Windows 10 and Ubuntu both.

Could someone help me resolve this?

(I had raised [another query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32862454/eclipse-mars-download-repository-index-updates-on-startup-fails) where similar issue happens behind company proxy but not sure if they are related.)

**Update:** I found that Eclipse m2e plugin was updating the index the afterall. It just was taking a long time to do it. But it doesn't update the status in the progress bar. **So this works**.
However, the problem with [company proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32862454/eclipse-mars-download-repository-index-updates-on-startup-fails) is still present.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to configure Proxy in Eclipse?
[Eclipse proxy configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43jcB.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The index in your company repository may be incorrect. This happened to me many times. I scheduled a job that regularly repairs and updates the indices in Nexus.